Two graviton two scalar vertex using FeynRules package
The model file I have used for generating two graviton two scalar vertex using FeynRules package doesn't give me the correct vertex. The correct vertex should have 18 terms in its full extended form. Any suggestion to fix it?
  (* ******** Particle classes ******** *)
    
    M$ClassesDescription = {
    
    (***  Graviton ***)
      T[1] == {
             ClassName -> h,
             SelfConjugate -> True,
             Symmetric -> True,
             Mass -> {Mh, 0}
             },
    
    
      S[1] == {
        ClassName       -> phi,
        SelfConjugate   -> True,
        Symmetric -> True,
        Mass            -> {M,Internal}
        
      }
    };
    
    
    
    (* ************      Parameters    ************ *)
    
    M$Parameters = {
    
    kappa    == { 
        ParameterType    -> External,
        Value            -> 0.00001, 
        TeX              -> kappa,
        Description      -> "Planck mass"
      }
    };
    
    (* ************************** *)
    (* *****   Lagrangian   ***** *)
    (* ************************** *)
    
    
    
    Lhh:=1/2 h[mu,lambda] h[nu,lambda] del[phi,mu] del[phi,nu] -1/4 h[alpha,alpha] h[mu,nu] del[phi, mu] del[phi, nu] -1/8 h[lambda,sigma] h[lambda,sigma] del[phi,lambda] del[phi,lambda] + 1/16 h[beta,beta] h[gamma,gamma] del[phi,lambda] del[phi,lambda] + 1/8 h[lambda,sigma] h[lambda,sigma] M^2 phi^2 -1/16 h[zeta,zeta] h[iota,iota] M^2 phi^2 

